# std::move disvalidates this pointer in std::bind

Tags: c++, multithreading, g++

I have a following class which takes care about a serial device. (Please keep in mind that I posted the minimal example which reproduces the problem I am observing. In reality there is a lot of error handling etc, which I removed for simplicity - thus don't judge me on that)

```
class Device
{
public:
    void open(const std::string& path) { 
        fd = ::open(path.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY));
        readThread = std::thread(std::bind(&Device::readProc, this)); 
    }
    void close() { ::close(fd); }

private:
    void readProc() { auto i = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); }
    std::thread readThread;
    int fd;
};
```

in main, i'll enumerate every device and if open was successfull, ill push it into the vector:

```
for (auto& p : std::filesystem::directory_iterator("/dev/"))
        if (p.path().string().substr(0, 11) == "/dev/ttyACM")
        {
            Device dev;
            if (dev.open(p.path().string()))
            {
                readers.push_back(std::move(dev));
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Failed to open device " << p.path() << std::endl;
            }
        }
```

the problem is, after calling `std::move(dev)` this pointer passed to `std::bind` function seems to be invalidated. read returns -1 with errno set to 9 (invalid descriptor). I've debugged it and after open the value of **fd** was 5 (changing with each program run) while in the **readProc()** it became -129589 (random value) after `std::move`.

Is this the correct behavior? If so, how can it be avoided?

**Edit:** I've changed the device enumeration to:

```
readers.emplace_back();
auto& dev = readers.back();
if (!dev.open(p.path().string()))
{
    readers.pop_back();
}
```

which worked like a charm, thus confirming my observations regarding std::move(), but it is far from correct way to do that.

Comment: @NathanOliver please see Device::open() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
readThread = std::thread(std::bind(&Device::readProc, this));
```

you bind `this` to the function passed to the thread. Then later when you call

```
readers.push_back(std::move(dev));
```

then `dev` is moved and the thread member is moved, but the thread still has a pointer to the moved from object.

In your fixed version, this is not the case, you call `open` on the `Device` that already is in the container.

> Is this the correct behavior?

Yes. After moving the object `dev` still has its `this` unchanged. And the object in the container is a different `this`.

> If so, how can it be avoided?

Be careful with references / pointers passed to threads. In general you need to take care that the object referenced / pointed to is still alive.

Comment: In this particular example, how would you bypass this? How would you make sure that after moving this points to a new address instead of the old one?

Comment: @Quest I would'nt move threads around if not absolutely necessary. Instead of `open` i would use a constructor and follow something very similar to your `emplace_back` approach

Comment: yeah well, the problem is, call to open might fail (insufficient permissions for example) which would force me to throw exceptions inside a constructor. (not sure how `emplace_back` would handle such situation.

Comment: @Quest the constructor is the right place to construct an object and throwing an exception from a constructor is the right thing to do when construction fails. `emplace_back` is exception safe afaik, ie the container is unmodified in case there is an exception.

Comment: @Quest see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back): "If an exception is thrown, this function has no effect (strong exception guarantee). " (though make sure to read the full exception specs, there are some exceptions)